# how remove special characters from the end of every word in a string?

Tags: python, regex

i want it match only the end of every word

example:

```
"i am test-ing., i am test.ing-, i am_, test_ing,"
```

output should be:

```
"i am test-ing i am test.ing i am test_ing"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> test = "i am test-ing., i am test.ing-, i am_, test_ing,"
>>> re.sub(r'([^\w\s]|_)+(?=\s|$)', '', test)
'i am test-ing i am test.ing i am test_ing'
```

Matches one or more non-alphanumeric characters (`[^\w\s]|_`) followed by either a space (`\s`) or the end of the string (`$`). The `(?= )` construct is a lookahead assertion: it makes sure that a matching space is not included in the match, so it doesn't get replaced; only the `[\W_]+` gets replaced.

Okay, but why `[^\w\s]|_`, you ask? The first part matches anything that's not alphanumeric or an underscore (`[^\w]`) or whitespace (`[^\s]`), i.e. punctuation characters. Except we do want to eliminate underscores, so we then include those with `|_`.

Comment: John: thanks for the reply, i'd like to know what's the difference between $ and \Z?

Comment: -1 Normally (non-MULTILINE) there *is* a difference; `$` perlishly matches the end of the input string OR A NEWLINE AT THE END OF THE STRING. `\Z` matches only at the end of the string, which is usually the desired behaviour.

Comment: more precisely: "OR just before A NEWLINE AT ..."

Comment: This solution also deletes excess whitespace between words, which is presumably an unintentional (and possibly undesirable) side-effect.

Comment: I think using `r'([^\w\s]|_)+(?=\s|$)'` instead will fix the whitespace deletion problem.

Comment: @jchl Good catch. I noticed this but thought I could get away with the simpler regex, ha.